# Cannot place images into Illustrator

Tags: adobe-illustrator

I cannot import images into Illustrator CS6. Dragging in doesn't work. "Place" command doesn't work. Any ideas? I have uninstalled and re-installed.

Comment: What happens when you use File > Place? Does it not open the dialog?

Comment: What kind of images? all types? some you are certain are not broken/corrupt? have you tried right-click -> open with?

Comment: It may sound stupid but... Are you trying to place on a locked layer?

Answer (score 1):

This problem has been reported before and was linked to plugins you may have either installed recently or updated recently. When you uninstalled Illustrator, the plugin files may have remained on your computer. If you did install plugins try removing them completely.